# Fermat Algorithm for prime factors calculation

Tags: algorithm, math, prime-factoring

According to youtube [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uigp4aLP2eM) **the prime factors** of an odd number can be calculated as follows:

a = sqrt(N + b^2)

I wrote below program to do that but I am not getting the prime factors of 2345678917. I know this is prime number but for other prime numbers the program does return 1 and the number itself but for this number it is not happening. Why?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void foo(unsigned long long x)
{
    int i;
    for (i=1;i<x;i++)
        if (fmod(sqrt(x + i*i), 1) == 0) {
            printf("%f %f\n", (sqrt(x + i*i) - i), (sqrt(x + i*i)+i));
            return;
        }
}

int main(void) {
    foo((unsigned long long)2345678917);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This question is still un-answered so please go ahead and post your solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the type of `i` (`int`) does not match `x` (`unsigned long long`). Change the type of `i` to `unsigned long long` to get going.

Once you do that, your program will proclaim happily that 14 * 167548494 = 2345678917. Of course, this is not true, since the product of two even numbers cannot be odd. The problem here is loss of precision, so you need to implement a square testing function for integers, rather than testing if the floating point square root is integral.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

unsigned long long find_sqrt(unsigned long long x)
{
    unsigned long long lo = 1;
    while (4 * lo * lo <= x) lo *= 2;
    unsigned long long hi = 2 * lo;
    while (lo + 1 < hi) {
        unsigned long long mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
        if (mid * mid <= x) lo = mid;
        else hi = mid;
    }
    return lo * lo == x ? lo : 0;
}

void foo(unsigned long long x)
{
    unsigned long long i;
    for (i=1;i<x;i++) {
        unsigned long long sqrt_x_ii = find_sqrt(x + i*i);
        if (sqrt_x_ii) {
            printf("%llu = %llu * %llu\n",
                   x, sqrt_x_ii - i, sqrt_x_ii + i);
            return;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    foo((unsigned long long) 2345678917);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, it's either very slow or stuck in an inf loop, I didn't stop it in a debugger to check.  It might be that it's just not finding any exact sqrts for a long time.

Comment: @nomanpouigt: The smallest `i` for which `2345678917 + i*i` is a square is `1172839458`.  You shouldn't really be surprised that calculating over a billion integer square roots takes more than 5 seconds.  In any case, this answer gives the essential information: namely, that you're running into difficulties with floating-point precision.  Note that for that value of `i`, `2345678917 + i*i` is `1375552396587412681`, which can't be represented exactly in an IEEE 754 binary64 double (which is probably what your platform is using).

Comment: @nomanpouigt: By the way, the code in this answer compiles and runs perfectly for me, producing the output `2345678917 = 1 * 2345678917`.  It does take a couple of minutes to give that result.